# Meteor.js accounts package

Tags: meteor

I'm looking to find out why Meteor.user() always shows only the current user, I'm using the Meteor accounts package.
[screenshot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/XJQl9.png)

Comment: Are you publishing other users? By default only the current user is published to the client.

Comment: thank a lot chazsolo that was it